# Can't Find Source Code of Live Share for Visual Studio (Windows, and not The VS Code Version)

Tags: c#

When I try to I Only find the linux version for VS Code.
The problem is the fact that it's built in to vs and therfore I can't find its source code.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Microsoft never released the source code of Live Share, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/38733

Answer (score 1):

**Live Share is not currently an open source product!**

As of this date (2021-02-14): The code is not available under any license. You can’t review, contribute or even compile the code because it is totally unavailable.